# How add product to cart with Angular and Firestore

Tags: html, angular, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I manage to fetch the product data through the URL and when I am on the product details page there is a button that allows me to add the product to a sub-collection of the logged in user.
Below is what I want:
`users/{userID}/shopping/{productID}`

`details-product.component.html` displaying information in product details

```
    <div class="uk-container panier" *ngIf="product">
        <div id="modal-center" class="uk-flex-top" uk-modal>
          <div class="uk-modal-dialog uk-modal-body uk-margin-auto-vertical">
              <button class="uk-modal-close-default" type="button" uk-close></button>
              <img [src]="(product | async)?.imageURL" class="nav-left">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="uk-child-width-1-2@s" uk-grid>
          <div>
            <a href="#modal-center" uk-toggle>
              <img [src]="(product | async)?.imageURL" class="nav-left" alt="">
            </a>
          </div>
          <div>
            <div class="uk-dark uk-padding">
              <h3> {{ (product | async)?.name }}</h3>
              <hr class="uk-divider-icon">
              <div class="uk-flex prix">
                <p class="uk-text">
                  <span>{{ (product | async)?.price | currency: 'XOF' }} </span>
                </p>
              </div>
              <hr class="uk-divider-icon">
              <button class="uk-button uk-button-default uk-form-width-medium" (click)="showDialog()">
               <i class='bx bxs-cart-add'></i>
                J'achète le produit
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

[image]

`shopping-cart.service.ts`

```
import { AngularFirestore, AngularFirestoreCollection } from '@angular/fire/compat/firestore';
import "firebase/auth";

import { User } from 'src/app/models/user.model';
import { Product } from 'src/app/models/product.model';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ShoppingCardService {

  userCollection: AngularFirestoreCollection<User>;
  productsCollection: AngularFirestoreCollection<Product>;

  constructor(private readonly dbstore: AngularFirestore) {
    this.userCollection = this.dbstore.collection('users');
    this.productsCollection = this.dbstore.collection('products');
  }

  addToMyCart(product: Product, userID: string, qteProduct: number) {
    const userDoc = this.dbstore.firestore.collection('users').doc(userID);
    const productDoc = this.dbstore.firestore.collection('products').doc(product.id);
    const userShoppingProduct = userDoc.collection('shopping');
    return userShoppingProduct.doc(product.id).set(product);
  }
}
```

`product.service.ts`

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFirestore, AngularFirestoreCollection } from '@angular/fire/compat/firestore';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Product } from 'src/app/models/product.model';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ProductsService {

    productCollection: AngularFirestoreCollection<Product>;
    
    constructor(private dbstore: AngularFirestore, private router: Router) {
      this.productCollection = this.dbstore.collection('products', (ref) => 
        ref.orderBy('category', 'desc')
      );
    }
    getDetailProduct(productId: string): Observable<any> {
      return this.productCollection.doc(productId).valueChanges();
    }
}
```

`details-product.component.ts`

```
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/internal/Observable';
import { User } from 'src/app/models/user.model';
import { Product } from 'src/app/models/product.model';
import { ProductsService } from '../../shared/services/products.service';
import { ShoppingCardService } from 'src/app/shared/services/shopping-card.service';
import { AngularFirestoreCollection } from '@angular/fire/compat/firestore';
import { AddToCartComponent } from './add-to-cart.component'
import { MatDialog } from '@angular/material/dialog';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-details-product',
  templateUrl: './details-product.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./details-product.component.css']
})
export class DetailsProductComponent implements OnInit {
  
  quantity: number = 0;
  productIdRoute: string;
  isMyProduct: boolean = false;
  product: Observable<Product>;
  userCollection!: AngularFirestoreCollection<User>

  constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private productService: ProductsService,
    private shoppingCardService: ShoppingCardService,
    private titleService: Title,
    private dialog: MatDialog,
  ) {
    const routeParams = this.route.snapshot.paramMap;
    this.productIdRoute = String(routeParams.get('productId'));
    this.product = this.productService.getDetailProduct(this.productIdRoute);
  }

  showDialog(): void {
    const data = this.dialog.open(AddToCartComponent, {
      width: '30rem',
      data: { productID: this.productIdRoute },
    });
    console.log(data);
  }
```

`add-to-cart.component.ts`
component in modal to confirm adding to cart

```
import { Component, OnInit, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { MatDialog, MAT_DIALOG_DATA } from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { ShoppingCardService } from '../../shared/services/shopping-card.service';
import { Product } from 'src/app/models/product.model';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-add-to-cart',
  template: `
    <div class="relative p-4 w-full max-w-md h-full md:h-auto">
            <div class="p-6 text-center">
                <svg aria-hidden="true" class="mx-auto mb-4 w-14 h-14 text-gray-400 dark:text-gray-200" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 24 24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M12 8v4m0 4h.01M21 12a9 9 0 11-18 0 9 9 0 0118 0z"></path></svg>
                <h3 class="mb-5 text-lg font-normal text-gray-500 dark:text-gray-400">Do you want to add this product?</h3>
                <button (click)="onAddPubpik(data.product, data.userID)" type="button" class="text-white bg-gray-800 hover:bg-gray-800 focus:ring-4 focus:outline-none font-medium rounded-lg text-sm inline-flex items-center px-5 py-2.5 text-center mr-2">
                   Yes, i add to cart
                </button>
            </div>
    </div>
  `,
  styleUrls: ['./details-product.component.css']
})
export class AddToCartComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(
    @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: { product: Product, userID: string, qteProduct: number },
    private dialog: MatDialog,
    private shoppingService: ShoppingCardService
  ) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  async onAddPubpik(product: Product, userID: string): Promise<void> {
    this.dialog.closeAll();
    const qteProduct = (product.quantity += 1);
    product.isMyProduct = true;
    await this.shoppingService.addToMyCart(product, userID, qteProduct);
  }

}
```

[image]

When i confirm, in console :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

On this line `const qteProduct = (product.quantity += 1);`, product is undefined. You’re not passing product to the matdialog component in your `showDialog()` method hence the error.